# pyspark parent child recursive on same dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have the following two Dataframes that stores diagnostic and part change for helicopter parts.
diagnostic dataframe stores the maintenance activities carried out date. The part change dataframe stores all part removals for all the helicopter parts, parent(rotor), and child (turbofan, axle, module).

What I am trying to achieve is quite complex, based on the diagnostic df I want to provide me the **first removal** for the same part along with its parent roll all the way up to so that I get the helicopter serial no at that **maintenance date**.

Here the initial code to generate the sample datasets:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window as W

diagnostic_list = [
  {"SN":"tur26666","PN": "turbofan", "maintenance":"23/05/2016"}
]
part_change_list= [
  {"SN":"tur26666","PN": "turbofan", "removal":"30/03/2019", "Parent_SN" : "com26666","Parent_PN": "compressor"},
{"SN":"tur26666","PN": "turbofan", "removal":"30/06/2016", "Parent_SN" : "com26666","Parent_PN": "compressor"},

 {"SN":"com26666","PN": "compressor", "removal":"13/03/2019", "Parent_SN" : "rot71777","Parent_PN": "rotorcraft"},
 {"SN":"com26666","PN": "compressor", "removal":"30/06/2016", "Parent_SN" : "rot26666","Parent_PN": "rotorcraft"},

 {"SN":"rot26666","PN": "rotorcraft", "removal":"31/12/2019", "Parent_SN" : "OYAAA","Parent_PN": "helicopter"},
  {"SN":"rot26666","PN": "rotorcraft", "removal":"24/06/2016", "Parent_SN" : "OYHZZ","Parent_PN": "helicopter"},    
]
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
diagnostic_df = spark.createDataFrame(Row(**x) for x in diagnostic_list)
part_change_df = spark.createDataFrame(Row(**x) for x in part_change_list)
```

```
diagnostic_df.show()


+--------+--------+-----------+
|      SN|      PN|maintenance|
+--------+--------+-----------+
|tur26666|turbofan| 23/05/2016|
+--------+--------+-----------+

part_change_df.show()


+--------+----------+----------+---------+----------+
|      SN|        PN|   removal|Parent_SN| Parent_PN|
+--------+----------+----------+---------+----------+
|tur26666|  turbofan|30/03/2019| com26666|compressor|
|tur26666|  turbofan|30/06/2016| com26666|compressor|
|com26666|compressor|13/03/2019| rot71777|rotorcraft|
|com26666|compressor|29/06/2016| rot26666|rotorcraft|
|rot26666|rotorcraft|31/12/2019|    OYAAA|helicopter|
|rot26666|rotorcraft|24/06/2016|    OYHZZ|helicopter|
+--------+----------+----------+---------+----------+
```

I was able to get the first removal for the child turbofan with the below code :

```
working_df = (
    diagnostic_df.join(part_change_df, ["SN", "PN"], how="inner")
    .filter(F.col("removal") >= F.col("maintenance"))
    .withColumn(
        "rank",
        F.rank().over(
            W.partitionBy([F.col(col) for col in ["SN", "PN", "maintenance"]]).orderBy(
                F.col("removal")
            )
        ),
    )
    .filter(F.col("rank") == 1)
    .drop("rank")
)
working_df.show()

+--------+--------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+
|      SN|      PN|maintenance|   removal|Parent_SN| Parent_PN|
+--------+--------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+
|tur26666|turbofan| 23/05/2016|30/06/2016| com26666|compressor|
+--------+--------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+
```

How can I create a for loop or a recursive loop within the part_change_df to get the results like this that takes each parent of the first child and makes it the next child and get the first removal information after the first child(turbofan)'s maintenance date)?

```
+--------+--------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|      SN|      PN|maintenance|   removal|Parent_SN| Parent_PN|Parent_removal|next_Parent_SN|next_Parent_PN|next_Parent_removal|next_next_Parent_PN|next_next_Parent_SN|
+--------+--------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|tur26666|turbofan| 23/05/2016|30/06/2016| com26666|compressor|    29/06/2016|      rot26666|    rotorcraft|         24/06/2016|         helicopter|              OYHZZ|
+--------+--------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

I could hardcode each parent and join working dataframe with the part change dataframe, but the problem i don't know exactly how high the number of parents a child will have .
The ultimate goal is like to get the child maintenance date and roll up all the way to the final parent removal date and the helicopter serial no:

```
+--------+--------+-----------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|      SN|      PN|maintenance|   removal|next_Parent_removal|next_next_Parent_PN|next_next_Parent_SN|
+--------+--------+-----------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|tur26666|turbofan| 23/05/2016|30/06/2016|         24/06/2016|         helicopter|              OYHZZ|
+--------+--------+-----------+----------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Why is `Parent_SN` sometimes different rot26666 and rot71777 but the `SN` is always the same rot26666? Is `SN` not unique?

Comment: yes SN is always unique , its like you have tyre wheel assembly and car, the tyre is always same and it moves between wheel assemblies and the wheel assemblies moves between cars.

Comment: @cronoik, to add to the answer, the loop will break when the parent_SN == helicopter that is when you have looped from SN all the way up to the top parent

Comment: Can you use [graphframes](https://graphframes.github.io/graphframes/docs/_site/index.html)?